# How to convert String of date format "dd-MMM-yy" into DateType

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Example "31-Jan-19" should be 2019-01-31
My code:

```
df.withColumn("formattedDate", to_date($"date", "dd-MMM-yyyy").cast(DateType))
//this line gives same result
df.withColumn("unixDate", to_date(unix_timestamp($"date", "dd-MMM-yyyy")
   .cast("timestamp")))
```

Result of this code: 0019-01-31

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In date format specify **`yy`** instead of **`yyyy`**.

```
df.withColumn("formattedDate", to_date($"date", "dd-MMM-yy").cast(DateType)).show()

//+---------+-------------+
//|     date|formattedDate|
//+---------+-------------+
//|31-Jan-19|   2019-01-31|
//+---------+-------------+

df.withColumn("unixDate", to_date(unix_timestamp($"date", "dd-MMM-yy").cast("timestamp"))).show()

//+---------+----------+
//|     date|  unixDate|
//+---------+----------+
//|31-Jan-19|2019-01-31|
//+---------+----------+
```